# How can I put my class in a package when I compile from command line?

Tags: java, compilation, package

I have a TestClass java in folder:

```
c:\foo\bar\TestClass.java
```

The code looks like this:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println("Hello World!");


    }
}
```

When I type

```
c:\foo\bar\javac TestClass.java
```

then

```
c:\foo\bar\java TestClass
```

I see hello world fine.

But I want to append

```
 package bar;
```

or

```
 package foo.bar;
```

to my class, because it is actually in folder: **foo\bar**

When I add

```
package bar;
```

and do this:

```
 c:\foo\javac bar\TestClass.java
```

compile is fine but when I try:

```
c:\foo\java bar\TestClass
```

I get: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** because the package information is wrong I believe.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Did you try `java bar.TestClass` from within `c:\foo`?

Comment: @DavidWallace I did not try that actually, thanks it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do

```
c:\foo>java bar.TestClass
```

instead

compiled class is different than just `TestClass` it is now `bar.TestClass` fully qualified

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the main method in a specific class inside a package, please specify the full path to the class. In your case this would be `bar.TestClass`, i.e.

```
c:\foo>java bar.TestClass
```

As you can see I replaced the file separator (`/`) with a `.`.